# Problems installing Ubuntu 18.04 on 1950x Threadripper with NVMe SSD

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, amd-processor, nvme

I made a bootable usb with ubuntu 18 on it. And I'm having issues installing ubuntu 18.04. Below is where it gets stuck.

I've edit the boot settings and set nomodeset when I pick "install ubuntu".

This is pretty new hardware with specs as:

- 1950x threadripper
- ASrock X399M TAICHI
- NVMe ssd
- old radeon card

What else can I do to fix these issues?

[image]

Comment: Make sure the BIOS and AGESA versions are the latest available, for your board?

Comment: yea i just checked and the bios is upto date with the latest it says. I did it via the bios as there was a feature in the bios to connect directly to the internet and update it.

Comment: Are you booting the installer in UEFI or legacy mode?

Comment: where do i even find that? and which one should I be on? @dobey

Comment: In the BIOS config (usually under boot options), and you should be using UEFI. But if you are, and this is happening, maybe try switching to Legacy to see if you can get booted far enough to run the memory test in the installer perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

After many months of trying and switching out parts. I finally found out the problem of these install issues. I had incompatible RAM, even thought it let the system boot, it was throwing me off to what was causing the issue.

Make sure you have compatible ram. Look it up according to your motherboard specs and buy those only.